# define a variable in configure.ac as output of a command

Tags: autotools

I need to declare a variable as the output of a command.
I tried with:

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([SVN_REV], ["$(shell svnversion -n .)"], [Define svn revision number])
```

and in config.h I find:

```
#define SVN_REV ""
```

If I try with:

```
AC_DEFINE([SVN_REV], ["$(shell svnversion -n .)"], [Define svn revision number])
```

in config.h there is:

```
#define SVN_REV "$(shell svnversion -n .)"
```

How can I make SVN_REV defined as the correct value in config.h?

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you seem to want in `configure.ac` alone.  This code:

```
$(shell svnversion -n .)
```

seems to be for when `make` is actually run.  When `configure` calls `AC_OUTPUT` all your `AC_DEFINE`s are written into `config.h` at that time.  Which is *before* `make`, so anything written at that time will not be in the `make` environment.  You can run this command in the `configure` environment:

```
SVNVERSION_REV=`svnversion -n .`
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([SVN_REV],
                   ["$SVNVERSION_REV"],
                   [Define svn revision number])
```

which has mostly the same effect.  The version number will be prone to staleness though (e.g. modifying files and committing them after `configure`).  The solution to this is to drive all the version stuff from `Makefile.am`, not `configure.ac`.

Getting that version information into autotools is a little tricky.  Here's a somewhat modified version of something I used to insert a subversion version into a .spec file.

First I grab the `svnversion` binary using [AX_WITH_PROG](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_with_prog.html) (or something like it):

**configure.ac**

```
# check for svnversion (not required, except for the maintainer)
AX_WITH_PROG([SVNVERSION], [svnversion])
```

**Makefile.am**

```
# copy svnstamp to svn-revision 
# if svn-revision non-existent or svnstamp is newer
svn-revision : $(top_builddir)/svnstamp
        if test ! -f $@ -o $< -nt $@; then \
            cp $< $@; \
        fi

# always do this check to avoid staleness
.PHONY : svnstamp_

# This is supposed to do nothing
# all the work to create this file is in svnstamp_
$(top_builddir)/svnstamp : svnstamp_
        @/bin/true

# run the command only if the codebase is a svn working copy
# I've taken out the RPM related strings so you might be able
# to plug it into your code more easily
svnstamp_ :
    if test -d $(top_srcdir)/.svn ; then \
      SVN_VERSION_STAMP=`$(SVNVERSION) $(top_srcdir) -n`; \
      NEW_STAMP=`echo -n "$$SVN_VERSION_STAMP"`; \
      if test ! -f $(top_builddir)/svnstamp; then \
        echo "$$NEW_STAMP" > $(top_builddir)/svnstamp; \
      else \
        OLD_STAMP=`cat $(top_builddir)/svnstamp`; \
        if test "$$OLD_STAMP" != "$$NEW_STAMP" ; then \
          echo "$$NEW_STAMP" > $(top_builddir)/svnstamp; \
        fi \
      fi \
    else \
      if test ! -f $(top_builddir)/svnstamp \
              -o $(top_srcdir)/svn-revision \
              -nt $(top_builddir)/svnstamp; then \
        cp $(top_srcdir)/svn-revision $(top_builddir)/svnstamp; \
      fi \
    fi; \
    NEW_STAMP=`cat $(top_builddir)/svnstamp`; \
    if test "x$$NEW_STAMP" = "x"; then \
      echo " Failed to make svnstamp"; \
      exit 1; \
    fi
```

In order to do this for your translation units that need the version stamp, you'll need to make them dependencies of `svn-revision` and do something like the following in the build step:

```
... -DSVN_REV=\"`cat svn-revision`\" ...
```

Comment: How can I move the version stuff in Makefile.am? I tried without success.